# How can I bundle Python 3.x to my Electron App that uses ReactJs?

Tags: python, reactjs, electron, publish

I have an electron application to be used on customers' computers.

The application needs to open IEDriver.exe to open some URLs with some proxies. So I am calling a python script that uses selenium and IEDriver via Python-Shell package.

When I build my electron application, It works well on my machine because I already installed Python 3.x. But when I publish it to customers' usage, the Python 3.x should be installed on their machines. So how can I bundle Python3.x with my application?

Here is my build configuration, Thanks in advance.

```
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build && npm run electron-build",
        "react-build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject",
        "electron-start": "electron .",
        "electron-build": "electron-builder",
        "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps"
    },
    "build": {
      "appId": "sampleAppId",
      "extends": null,
      "win": {
        "asar": true,
        "target": "nsis",
        "icon": "./build/assets/icon.png"
      },
      "nsis": {
        "oneClick": true,
        "installerLanguages": "en_US",
        "displayLanguageSelector": true,
        "multiLanguageInstaller": true,
        "unicode": true
      },
      "files": [
        "./build/**/*",
        "./public/Main.js",
        "./src/electron/*"
      ]
     }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can bundle everthing using. [Innosetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php).

You can use [Standalone - Portable Winpython](https://winpython.github.io/).

Comment: What about for mac and linux users?